# experiment: it is possible to find with element has been affected by a class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

This is not really something practical but I was wondering if its possible to find with elements of the DOM has been affected by a class or div or any other form of css selector.

For example I have a selector that puts a red border around a div and I want to use pure javascript to return with element of the DOM has a red border.

And to add dificulty, document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll are not an option.

Again, I know that is something strange, but It's just a doubt.

Comment: Is this a case of you don't know about built-in browser developer tools or you can't use them because you have a different requirement in mind? If you right click and "Inspect Element" in most modern browsers, it will show you the CSS affecting whatever tag you select.

Comment: I know that! But I want to know if something like that can be archived from javascript. The goal, is to reach an html element by using CSS. I also know that javascript already has methods to select DOM elements. Like I said, is an experiment.

Comment: OK I was just looking out for an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Carry on. =)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use something like:

```
elements = document.querySelector('any-css-selector');
```

Comment: This not answer the question. How do you detect `any-css-selector` has a red border?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify that I can't use `document.querySelector´ or ´document.querySelectorAll `

Comment: However this answer has 2 votes and its not a valid answer. @LuanNico it's possible that you have some friends that gives you upvotes? Do you know that's illegal?=

Comment: @Sergio Why you can't use querySelectors ?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Like I said, is and experiment! It was a test for a coding job that I solve using a javascript, loops and HTML collections, So, don't worry you are not doing my homework hahaha. But I was wondering if something like my question can be archived. The test prohibits the use of  document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll it's not a functional requeriment, just a mind melting thing.

Comment: HaHaHa!! But you said `using a javascript, loops and HTML collections,`. querySelector is javascript!! It's better performance than manual DOM iterate. I don't know why we are talking in this answer, this discussion is related to my answer....

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't really understood the question. I thought the red border was merely an example. My bad. Clearly I wasn't the only one to misinterpret it, though, thus the upvotes.

Comment: @LuanNico Ok! No problem. The only thing is this is not a valid answer . Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

You can perfectly. The only problem is the CPU load of your browser can be so hard, and it's not good for users, because you need to read all DOM elements and return only which have your conditions.

### JQuery solution

```
  $('html *').each(function(){
        alert($(this).css('border-color'));
  });
```

### Javascript solution

```
  var els = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
  for(var i in els) {
       var comp = window.getComputedStyle(els[i]);
       var result = comp.getPropertyValue("border-color");
       alert(result);
   }
```

### EDIT

Documentation for `getComputedStyle`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that I can't use document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll anyway... getComputedStyle and get PropertyValue can work. I'm going to test it.

Comment: I attach you documentation